# NodeJS - ifUserExist

Tags: node.js, exists

I'm building a user system in Node JS at the moment and I'm now against a bug, to create my session, i would like to check if the user exist in my database, so i looked for some solutions and i foud what I wanted, i have to do it by a query and a "rowCount". But I've been trying this for a week and I can't. My query seems not to be working and i don't find the problem, and certainly not the solution. I give you my code, could you please help me ? Thx a lot !

```
`app.get('/connection', (request, response) => {
    response.render('pages/connect', {error: '', success: ''})
})

// Posting from connect.ejs
app.post('/connection', (request, response) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = ? and password = ?', [request.body.email,request.body.password], (err, results) => {
        var numRows = results.length;
        if(numRows == 1){
            response.render('pages/index', {error: '', success: ''})
        }else{
            response.render('pages/connect', {error: 'a', success: ''})
        }
    });
})`
```

Answer (score 0):

try the query as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE mail = ? and password = ?
```

This will give you the number of rows which match the criteria. So you won't find the length of result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot man ! I found the problem, but please don't juge me! The problem was that the password element was encrypted in sha1 in my database, what a shamy issue! So I solved it by encrypting the password **before** query, it works perfectly.